# `rpm -q` and `yum` break after `rpm --rebuild`

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm, rpmbuild

In order to repair the RPM database, I ran `rpm --rebuild`. Afterward, I cannot find any package using `rpm -qa`, and `yum` does not work，as the logs below show.

```
[root@local03 ~]# yum

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 294, in user_main errcode = main(args)
File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 115, in main base.getOptionsConfig(args)
File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 228, in getOptionsConfig self.conf
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/init.py", line 910, in conf = property(fget=lambda self: self._getConfig(),
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/init.py", line 299, in _getConfig startupconf = config.readStartupConfig(fn, root)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/config.py", line 892, in readStartupConfig startupconf.releasever = _getsysver(startupconf.installroot, startupconf.distroverpkg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/config.py", line 1043, in _getsysver hdr = idx.next() StopIteration

[root@local03 ~]# rpm -aq | grep bash 
[root@local03 ~]#
```

Comment: I get nothing using rpm -qa ,is there anyone could help me，I cannot thank you more.

Comment: Do you have any special settings in /etc/yum/yum.conf or other files in directories in /etc/yum/?  It looks to me, based on that error, that the error you are seeing is due to it being unable to parse your system version.

Comment: However, if `rpm -qa` doesn't return anything, then it sounds to me like you initialized your RPM database.  Might be time to restore from backups.

Comment: The version of my system is redhat 6.6,but I did not initialized my RPM database,I am sure I just rebuilded it. The files in `/etc/yum/yum.conf ` look normal.

Comment: The configuration for yum bears no relationship on rebuilding your rpm database. You’ve destroyed it and need to reinstall or restore from backups.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, is what I use to rebuild rpm database in centos, should work for rhel as well:

```
rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__*
rpm --rebuilddb
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but it did not work ，and I tried 3 times，the __db.00{1..4} was created after `rpm --rebuilddb`, the time of this files was lastest,Or should I back up something before `rebuilddb`？I feel confused.